# Couchbase cbbackup fails from remote server

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase

Couchbase cbbackup failing from the remote server, which has full connectivity to the Couchbase running on K8s.

- Couchbase Server version: couchbase: community-6.0.0
- Couchbase running on Kubernetes 1.17.

```html
cbbackup -m full http://{IP}:61006 /backup-1 -u admin -p password -vvv
```

> error: SASL auth socket error: 192.168.72.10:11210, timed out

cbbackup log added below,

```html
mt cbbackup...
mt  source : http://{IP}:61006
mt  sink   : /backup-1
mt source_class: <class 'pump_dcp.DCPStreamSource'>
mt Starting new HTTP connection (1): {IP}
mt "GET /pools/default/buckets HTTP/1.1" 200 19966
mt sink_class: <class 'pump_bfd.BFDSink'>
mt source_buckets: bucket-1
mt bucket: bucket-1
mt  source_nodes: 192.168.72.10:8091
mt  enqueueing node: 192.168.72.10:8091
mt rest_request: <ud>admin</ud>@{IP}:61006/pools/default/buckets/bucket-1/stats/curr_items; reason: total_msgs
w0  node: 192.168.72.10:8091
w0 sink_bucket: bucket-1
w0   DCPStreamSource connecting mc: 192.168.72.10:11210
s0   create_db: /backup-1/2020-07-28T083342Z/2020-07-28T083342Z-full/bucket-bucket-1/node-192.168.72.10%3A8091/data-0000.cbb
s0   connect_db: /backup-1/2020-07-28T083342Z/2020-07-28T083342Z-full/bucket-bucket-1/node-192.168.72.10%3A8091/data-0000.cbb
mt rest_request: <ud>admin</ud>@{IP}:61006/pools/default/buckets/bucket-1/stats/vb_active_resident_items_ratio; reason: total_msgs
w0   pump (http://{IP}:61006(bucket-1@192.168.72.10:8091)->/backup-1(bucket-1@192.168.72.10:8091)) done.
w0   source : http://{IP}:61006(bucket-1@192.168.72.10:8091)
w0   sink   : /backup-1(bucket-1@192.168.72.10:8091)
w0          :                total |       last |    per sec
w0  node: 192.168.72.10:8091, done; rv: (u'error: SASL auth socket error: 192.168.72.10:11210, timed out', None)
(u'error: SASL auth socket error: 192.168.72.10:11210, timed out', None)
```

*Raised issue in Couchbase forum as well. Refer [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-cbbackup-fails-from-remote-server/26950).*

Any idea about this? I am stuck with this issue.

**Update**
I can't use the exposed memcached port for cbbackup as no option added in the official [document](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbbackup-tool.html)..
[This](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-cbbackup-on-kubernetes-docker-issues/10544/3) answer posted in the Couchbase forum gives some details. If that is true then, its not possible to run a successful cbbackup from a remote system. But I don't think the Couchbase team has designed in that way. Hope there is way to achieve the same.

- Backing up and Restoring a Couchbase is tested and working using Kubernetes Jobs. But looking for a remote Couchbase backup.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here looks like  is that you have SASL authentication configured on your couchbase server/bucket. Also, looks like  the pod IP is `192.168.72.10` so the client is trying to authenticate from the same pod network but you are issuing the request from a different machine that is not in your Kubernetes cluster (I assume).

You can try running the backup from a pod:

```sh
$ kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=couchbase --restart=Never -- /opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackup -m full http://{IP}:61006 /backup-1 -u admin -p password -vvv
```

Unfortunately, `kubectl run` doesn't have a lot of functionality so you'll probably have to create your own Kubernetes YAML manifest if you'd like to to mount a volume.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: couchbase-backup
spec:
  containers:
  - name: couchbase-backup
    image: couchbase
    command: ["/opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackup"]
    args: ["-m", "full", "http://{IP}:61006", "/backup-1", "-u", "admin", "-p", "password", "-vvv"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: storage
      mountPath: /backup-1
  volumes:
  - name: storage
    ...
```

✌️☮️

Comment: thanks @Rico, you got it right "`the pod IP is 192.168.72.10 so the client is trying to authenticate from the same pod network but you are issuing the request from a different machine that is not in your Kubernetes cluster`", I was trying to achieve the backup from a remote server, this backup we can think as similar to mysqldump/pg_dump. But throwing issues for memcached port 11210.Backup & restore I have configured using K8s jobs like cronjob & job.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you think it's correct/helpful?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to make some security compromises. There is a reason why they've disabled remote SASL authentication.  You can try disabling in the couchbase configs.

Comment: Apparently SASL is the only available option in couchdb for username/password: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/security/authentication-overview.html#authentication-for-applications

Comment: With SASL the client needs to send a challenge and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: "External accessibility, which is available only with the Enterprise Edition of Couchbase Server, means either:" Thanks @Rico for the (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/security/authentication-overview.html#authentication-for-applications)[link]. Does that mean, we could achieve remote backup in enterprise edition.

Comment: (couchbase is not couchdb, just wanted to iterate that to prevent anyone going down a couchdb rabbit hole)

Comment: Thanks @MatthewGroves

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, backup from an external network is not possible with Couchbase 6.0.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbbackup-tool.html#description

> The cbbackup, cbrestore, and cbtransfer tools do not communicate with external IP addresses for server nodes outside of a cluster. Backup, restore, or transfer operations are performed on data from a node within a Couchbase Server cluster. They only communicate with nodes from a node list obtained within a cluster. This also means that if Couchbase Server is installed with a default IP address, an external hostname cannot be used to access it.

This caveat is not present in the documentation for 6.5... I think that's because 6.5 introduced [alternate addresses](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/learn/clusters-and-availability/connectivity.html#alternate-addresses) for connecting from outside the network.